# Change the data in a third-party mmc snap-in

Tags: windows, mmc, snap-in

There is 3-rd party application which is controlled by the console mmc, using a snap-in. What are some ways to interact with the data in this snap-in from the outside? (except of course the manual). There is a list of data I want to change, but it's hours of routine work. I would like to automate.

I need to add phones in this table (on the right). I have data in .txt
[image: Add data here]

By manual rows added by clicking right mouse button on "Маршруты SIP" (selected on screen), and then filling this form:

[image: form to add data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is quite open. A snap in is basically an Active-X module that is used to do something specific. **IF** there are public functions available to edit the data then you can do it easily.

Other ways:
It depends how the data is stored, if it is a flatfile / registry / database then you can automate the process by creating your own handler functions for the data.

The basics are, if it has public access it is easy otherwise it depends how the data is stored.

Comment: Thanks! I add some info, can it help to get some more details about solution?

Comment: The handler for that database would be very easy to make, create the link to the database and parse the text file, then manipulate the data in the way you need. A very simple solution indeed.

If you need help with implementation of the solution just ask.